# How do I make an installer with TurboStudio?

Tags: windows, virtualization, installer

I've been using [TurboStudio](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://turbo.net/studio&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwja5L23z8_UAhVG6GMKHeo3CkcQFggLMAA&usg=AFQjCNG3zHLRIFGDo_IUW2IT5k25EPcAzA) for some time now, and have become very good at using it. However, there seems to be a feature on it I cant seem to understand. There is an "Install" option in the list of tools, but it doesn't seem to work when I attempt to use it. Does anyone know how to create an installer with this feature? I have attempted to do this both from capturing an installation of the desired program, and by manually creating a project. `.msi` or `.exe` packages are accaptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://turbo.net/docs/deploying/portable-exes-and-msis):

EXEs:

> To produce an executable output, set the **Project Type** to **ISV Application** in TurboStudio. Executables can be deployed directly to the users device or to a network share and do not have any dependency requirements.

MSIs:

> To build an MSI, go to the Setup section of TurboStudio, enter the MSI
>   details and click **Build MSI**. MSIs can be deployed with existing
>   desktop management tools or directly by the end users.

Possible caveat:

> An enterprise license for TurboStudio is required to enable MSI outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do have an enterprise license, I'll give your answer a shot.